# ng2-pdfjs-viewer - Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, pdf.js, ng2-pdfjs-viewer

When  running my application with `ng serve` everything works fine. But after building it with `ng build --prod` I get ...

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 
'assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html' 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'assets/pdfjs/web/viewer.html'
```

... at the moment the pdfviewer component should be displayed. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Heinob, I struggled with the same issue as you and ultimately gave up trying to get this particular PDF viewer to work in angular after making various attempts to add the static route. I found a different PDF viewer that works right out of the box which is very similar to this one and doesn't throw that error when deploying to production. Here's a link to that 3rd party module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 4):

Add below snippet to

`"projects.your-project-name.architect.build.options.assets"`

array in `angular.json` which is basically `"assets"`

```
{
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "./node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer/pdfjs",
    "output": "/assets/pdfjs"
}
```

NOTE: It is `/assets/pdfjs` even though your assets is inside `src` folder.

It will automatically copy `pdfjs` folder in `node_modules/ng2-pdfjs-viewer`. It is better than manually copying the files because manually copying files may cause version inconsistency on package update.

Comment: Also  folder assets/pdfjs  should be existed

Comment: @YasarArafath No need. Angular will do it for you.

Comment: its  not doing i think so

Comment: It's will appear after you build the application @YasarArafath

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, but I solved it. Record my solution. I hope it will help.

1. Find the ng2-pdfjs-viewer folder in the node_modules folder;
2. Copy the pdfjs to the assets folder in the project
3. Restart

My environment: angular5.2.10 + ionic5.4.13 + ng2-pdfjs-viewer (latest version as of March 12, 2020)